# Where do installed add-on extensions appear in GRASS GUI

Tags: grass-gis, gui, add-ons

I have just started using the GRASS GIS GUI, and went onto `settings` to install the `v.krige` add-on extension

It has successfully completed, but I can't find where it is on the GUI to run it?

Answer (score 1):

Addons in GRASS do not automatically get added to the GUI. However if you simple run the addon command, with no parameters, at the GRASS console you should get a GUI window for entering the command parameters. (I don't know specifically about `v.krige`. If you encounter a problem, please consider to post back, and/or open an issue at [GRASS github issues](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues)